# Stop propagation on specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a drop down menu within a header using Bootstrap `data-toggle="dropdown"`. When you click the drop down button, a list should appear. When you click the header, the content should slide up and down.

The problem is, when I click the drop down button it also triggers the header. The usual answer here is `e.stopPropagation` but when I use that, it also stops the drop down menu from appearing.

How can I prevent the dropdown button from triggering the header?

**HTML**

```
<div id="top">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
      Show List
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li>Some Item</li>
      <li>Some Item</li>
      <li>Some Item</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="content" class="collapse">
  This is the actual content
</div>
```

**JS**

```
// CANNOT USE BOOTSTRAP DATA-TARGET !
$('#top').click(function() {
  $('#content').collapse('toggle')
})
$('button').click(function(e) {
  //e.stopPropagation();
})
```

I have prepared a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/58rfxgmy/2/) that illustrates this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should instead filtering regarding `event.target` of click on `#top` element:

```
$('#top').click(function(e) {
  if($(e.target).closest('button[data-toggle], .dropdown-menu').length) return;
  $('#content').collapse('toggle')
})
```

### -jsFiddle-

Comment: Sorry friend, this is still triggering the main content slide down when the drop down button is clicked. It should not trigger both.

Comment: I edited it, didn't get what was your expected behaviour

Answer (score 0):

You can do this as well.

```
// CANNOT USE BOOTSTRAP DATA-TARGET !
$('#top').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.type != "button"){
      $('#content').collapse('toggle')
  } 
})
$('button').click(function(e) {
  //e.stopPropagation();
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it, use `e.target` to determine if the clicked element is `#top`:

```
$('#top').click(function(e) {
   if(e.target.id=="top"){
        $('#content').collapse('toggle')
   } 
})
$('button').click(function(e) {
  //e.stopPropagation();
})
```